# Docker. How to pass arguments to FROM clause?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile with such contents:

```
# myimage
ARG NODE_VERSION=10
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}
...
```

I want user can specify that argument in its own Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml like that

```
# user_image
ARG NODE_VERSION=12
FROM myimage
...
```

It seems like that approach is not working

Comment: I'm pretty new to docker, so suggest better title, please

Comment: You can do this with Build command, use docker-compose for running the app. build with docker build. `NODE_VERSION=12 docker build -t imageName .`

Comment: @JinnaBalu it'll set an environment variable. Does it affect `ARG` variables?

Comment: Simply use `--build-arg` flag with variables and vales defined in Dockerfile, like  `docker build --build-arg NODE_VERSION=12 ............`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the Default Docker Environment Variables During Image Build is possible using `ARG` to pass through `--build-arg` flag with variable and its values right into ENV.

The  best practice is to create image and run the container isolated as follows.

Create a `Dockerfile`

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=default_value
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}
.....
.....
ENV NODE_VERSION=$NODE_VERSION
....
...
```

- Build the image with `docker build --build-arg NODE_VERSION=12 -t platform-ops .`
- Run the `platform-ops` image with docker-compose.yml

Create a `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: platform-ops
    .....
    ....
```

RUN with `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: How can i provide a default value for that thing?

Comment: how do you pass `build: args: ...` along with `image` in `docker-compose.yml` to build with needed parameters? It throws an error `Service xxxxx has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided`

Comment: You might be tryting to build with compose. Try to do it isolated.

Comment: So, I will not be able to share it with other developers. Each one will be forced to make builds themselves. I thought there was a way to do it once in config